# html can't place elements properly

Tags: html, css

So, I,m new to html and trying to make a plot with html and js. But I can't seem to place the element properly. Here's the piece of code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        #figurecontainer {
            margin: 0px;
            width: 960px;
            height: 800px;
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }
        .scatterlayer .trace:last-child path {
            pointer-events: all;
        }
    </style>

    <title>My Plotter</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input style="float:left; width:20%; " type="file" id="input">
    <div style="float:left; width:20%;" id="status" ><p>Load Data to plot</p></div>
    <input style="display: none ; width: 100px" id="saveMe" type="button" value="SaveData">    
    <div >
        <p style="float: left; width: 100px">X column</p>
        <p >Y column</p>
    </div>
    <div> 
        <select  style="width:100px"  id="xcolumn">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
        <select style="width:100px" id="ycolumn">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="figurecontainer"></div>


    <script>
        // some js
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I want the first three element on 1st row, then "X column" and "Y column" in next and finally the two dropdown box on 3rd row alined with the Column names. How can I do that?

EDIT: The fiure blocks others elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        body {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .row {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
        input[type=file] {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 15px;
        }
        #status {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 15px;
        }
        .saveMe {
            display: inline-block;
        }
    </style>

<title>My Plotter</title>
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="file" id="input">
        <div id="status" >Load Data to plot</div>
        <input id="saveMe" type="submit" value="SaveData">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p style="float: left; width: 100px">X column</p>
        <p >Y column</p>
    </div>

<div class="row"> 
    <select  style="width:100px"  id="xcolumn">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
    <select style="width:100px" id="ycolumn">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="6">6</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="figurecontainer"></div>


<script>
var layout = {
    autosize: true,
    showlegend: false,
    margin: {
        t: 20,
        r: 10,
        b: 30,
        l: 30,
        pad: 0
    },
    xaxis: {
        range: [0, 8],
        fixedrange: false,
        layer: 'below traces'
    },
    yaxis: {
        range: [0, 51],
        fixedrange: false,
        layer: 'below traces'
    },
    font: {size: 16}
};

var breakpoints = {
    x: [1, 8],
    y: [5, 30],
    type: 'scatter',
    cliponaxis: false,
    mode: 'markers',
    marker: {
        size: 5,
        symbol: "circle-open-dot",
        color: '#b00',
        line: {
            width: 2
        }
    },
    hoverinfo: 'x+y'
};

var figurecontainer = document.getElementById("figurecontainer");
Plotly.plot(figurecontainer, [breakpoints], layout);
</script>
```

Comment: If you search for "css flexbox cheat sheet" you will find some ideas which might help. Also, please try to avoid putting styles directly on elements because it makes it more fiddly to make adjustments later on.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a mixed types of positioning elements that is why your web-page was not structured correctly, but for beginners it is ok. I changed your code a little bit and here is the final html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <style>
  html {
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
  }
  .row {
   float: left;
   width: 100%;
  }
  input[type=file] {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 15px;
  }
  #status {
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 15px;
  }
  .saveMe {
   display: inline-block;
  }
    </style>

    <title>My Plotter</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="row">
  <input type="file" id="input">
  <div id="status" >Load Data to plot</div>
  <input id="saveMe" type="submit" value="SaveData">
 </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p style="float: left; width: 100px">X column</p>
        <p >Y column</p>
    </div>
 
    <div class="row"> 
        <select  style="width:100px"  id="xcolumn">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
        <select style="width:100px" id="ycolumn">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="figurecontainer"></div>


    <script>
        // some js
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well thanks for the help but the figure over shadows the other elements. I'm using `<br style="line-height: 7">` for now.

Comment: Do you want to add margin between rows? If it is so, you can simply add margin-bottom: 7px; for every row